# Reducing code duplication in constructors of subclasses

Tags: java, android, inheritance, constructor

SO here's the situation. I am extending a class in Java and I Need to provide 3 constructors with 1, 2 and 3 parameters respectively.

```
public class MessageButton extends ImageButton {
    private String number;

    public MessageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if( attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number") != null ) {
            this.number = attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number");
        }
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if( attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number") != null ) {
            this.number = attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number");
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously there's a bit of duplication there (in the last two constructors) and I want to reduce this.

I see two options:

1. Move the code into a setup() function, and call that from each constructor. This reduces the duplicated code, but still requires the call in each constructor.
2. Use this() in all but the last constructor. The only issue is that the defaults for the optional parameters are not null. I would need to check the source of the superclass to work out what values to use.

SO the way I see it, either way I have to duplicate code (the function call) or make assumptions about the superclass (the default values). I know both of these are less than desirable but which is the greater evil?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, I would use this() for all your constructors and check which default values are used in the parent class and supply those instead of null (used in this example). You are using this class for your custom code, so you should know what values you want as default.

```
public class MessageButton extends ImageButton {

    private String number;

    public MessageButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if (attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number") != null) {
            this.number = attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the rationale I couldn't get my head around! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call one constructor from another (without creating a new instance) with `this`

```
public MyClass(String value) {
  ....
}

public MyClass() {
  this(defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I would need to know the default values of parameters 2 and 3. (for example, the call in the first constructor would be `this(context, "default1", "default2")`. I can't do that without looking at the source of the superclass and assuming it won't change. I don't know if an assumption like that is better than the duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MessageButton extends ImageButton {
    private String number;

    public MessageButton(Context context) {
        this(context,null,0);
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);
    }

    public MessageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if(attrs!=null){
            if( attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number") != null ) {
               this.number = attrs.getAttributeValue("uk.co.gsteinert.ssbb", "number");
        }
        }}
}
```